# How do I load a software defined asset in dagster from outside dagster?

Tags: dagster

I'm failry new to dagster, but I really hope it has the feature of loading a software deffined asset from outside dagster.

To explain my ask:

consider this dagster graph:

```py
@asset
def users()->list[int]:
    return [1,2,3]

@asset
def new_users(users)->list[int]:
    return [u for u in users if is_new(u)]
```

The details don't really matter, just that there is some dag that generates some output.

Outside the dagster project, I have some jupyter notebooks. I'd like to be able to load the `new_users` list. If I had to invent an API for it I'd look something like:

```py
# In some jupyter notebook for example
from dagster.{something} import Project 

project = Project(...)

new_users = project.load_asset(asset='load_asset', force_refresh=False)
```

Does dagster have this type of functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Dagster has the `load_asset_value()` function for that, see the docs under https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/assets/software-defined-assets#loading-asset-values-outside-of-dagster-runs

Comment: This almost solves my problem, just need to figure out how to specify where the files are being saved. Currently getting file not found errors.

Comment: You might need to make sure that the DAGSTER_HOME env variable is set to a value and that it's the same value both for your Jupyter notebook and for when you're materializing the asset with Dagster.

Answer (score 0):

Dagster stores the asset "cache" as pickle files, so assuming you use the default /data directory, you can do:

```py
import pickle
import os

base_artifact_dir = '..\data'

def load_artifact(targ_file:str):
    targ_path = os.path.join(base_artifact_dir,targ_file)

    with open(targ_path,'rb') as fp:
        test_artifact = pickle.load(fp)

    return test_artifact
```

... where you can get the targ_file string quickly from your Dagster UI; clicking on an asset node gives a "path" entry on your right-hand-side, e.g. path : data\asset_key" and the pickle file's name will align with the asset_key. (if you remember your asset key from your asset definition you can use it directly too).

If you configured your storage setup differently you'll have to point at the correct base directory.  Also your run environment should be the same virtual environment as your Dagster environment, otherwise your pickle file may not unpack properly.